# Using enum vs variable, to store non-type template parameter value. (within Int2Type<int v> template)

Tags: c++, c++11

Going through *Modern C++ Design* by Andrei Alexandrescu, I am unable to understand the reason for using unnamed, unscoped `enum`, to store the non-type parameter.
Why not use a variable directly.

Does it have any advantages?

```
template <int v>
struct Int2Type
{
   enum { value = v }; //why not use int value = v; which compiles fine
};
```

Extra (if that helps): The template is intended to be used as a "type generator" to select different functions at compile time.

Comment: @drescherjm wrong. `static const int` was always allowed to be initialized inline.

Comment: Enums are nice to give *names* to values (if nothing else).

Comment: In what way is this question unclear or opinion based?  This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason to use `enum` instead of `static const int` or C++11 `static constexpr int` is that that enum gives you true prvalue, pretty much like literal int. That becomes important when issues of ODR manifest itself.

For example, following piece of code works fine (complete example):

```
void foo(const int& x) {
    std::cout << "X: " << x;
}

struct V {
    enum {value = 42; }
};

void bar() {
    foo(V::value);
}
```

On the other hand, following definition of struct exhibits undefined behavior (ODR violation):

```
struct V {
    static const int value = 42;
    // same with static constexpr int value = 42;
};
```

The reason for this is that binding reference to the value (when calling `foo`) ODR-uses value when it is a const member. All ODR-used variables have to be defined.

However, since references can't bind to enum members (and literals) a temporary is created, to which reference is bound to, so there is nothing to define. This is a very useful feature.

Comment: Is there ever a reason to use `static const int` and `static constexpr int` over `enum`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 who am I to say there is no reason or there is a reason? :) `static constexpr int` reads more naturally. Also, since there are `static constexpr double`s, the code becomes more uniform.

Comment: Very timely question, and answer... we were just discussing this at work today. +1

Comment: ODR always boggles my mind. I have two follow-up questions.1)What if I provide definition (in global scope) for the static. 2) Was ``` static ``` used to allow access to variable withlut initializing class object? or can I just use a normal variable? It compiles alright.

Comment: @User10482 answering the first question - yes, you can provide definition outside of the class, likely in .cpp file (absence inline variables in C++17). That is inconvenient. As for the second question, I think it's broad enough to warrant it's own separate question.